Weighted Least Squares versus ordinary least squares wiki page
If I have a $(X, Y)$ dataset and want to model $y = f(x, \beta)$. In that case for OLS, I would have
$$e(x_i, \beta) = f(x_i, \beta) - y_i$$
Then obviously I would have
$$SSE = \sum_{i}e(x_i, \beta)^2$$
and in a closed form
$$\frac{\partial SSE}{\partial \beta}|_{\hat{\beta}} = 0$$
while in a numeric form,
$$\underset{\beta}{\text{min}} SSE(\beta)$$
But according to the wikipedia article, this is only the case when the variance is absolutely constant.
Now, what does this statement mean? Does it mean that $|e(x_i, \hat{\beta})| = const..., \forall x_i$, i.e. $|e(x_1, \hat{\beta})| = |e(x_2, \hat{\beta})| = |e(x_3, \hat{\beta})| = |e(x_4, \hat{\beta})| = .....\text{so on and so forth} $
Now, failing this assumtion, a better estimator of $\beta$ would be
$$\underset{\beta}{\text{min}} \quad \sum_{i} w_i e(x_i, \beta)^2$$
Where $w_i = 1/{\sigma_i}^2$
How exactly is $\sigma_i$ defined here? Is it $\sigma_i = \sqrt{e(x_i, \beta)^2}$?
How is the equality of $\sigma_i$ enforced?

Do you have any apriori knowledge on the weights?

Not really. All I have apriori is the $(X, Y)$ dataset and the generic model $y = f(x, \beta)$ to which I would want to fit my dataset in the process of estimating $\hat{\beta}$

Is there strong evidence that there is heteroskedasticity?

Wouldn't call it strong, but $|e(x, \hat{\beta})|$ does not necessarily show a monotonic relationship with $x$. Of course there are select areas where $|e(x, \hat{\beta})|$ are larger where the model $f(x, \beta)$ changes signs especially in its higher order derivatives, other than that I don't think so. That's why I wanted to know, what would be a forebearing sign of heteroskedsticity and what does constant variance even mean mathematically.

If I read your post correctly, constant variance indicates that the variance of the error term conditional on $x$ is not a function of $x$; a condition which is generally termed "homoskedasticity".

If could say, that there is some way you could think of variance clustering, then weighted least squares could be useful, otherwise not.

Since the article you linked is focussed on linear regression, I will answer assuming that $f(x_{i},\beta) = x_{i}^{T}\beta$, for simplicity.
The simplest model, under homoskedasticity is assumed to be $y_{i} = x_{i}^{T}\beta + \varepsilon_{i}, i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, with $E[\varepsilon_{i}] = 0$ and $E[\varepsilon_{i}^{2}] = \sigma^{2}$ (if you want you can make these expectations conditional on $X$, but for simplicity I will assume that regressors $X$ are fixed). In matrix notation this would be $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$ with $E[\varepsilon] = 0$ and $E[\varepsilon\varepsilon^{T}] = \Sigma$ with $\Sigma = \sigma^{2}I$, with $I$ an identity matrix of size $n$. The variance being constant refers to the fact that the true residuals $\varepsilon_{i}$ all have variance $\sigma^{2}$ under this model. If this is the case, then OLS, which minimises
$$
SSE(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i} - x_{i}^{T}\beta)^{2} = (Y-X\beta)^{T}(Y-X\beta),
$$
is optimal among the class of linear unbiased estimators (BLUE), in the sense that $var(\hat{\beta})$ is smallest among this class.
Suppose now that you have heteroskedasticity, then the model is the same as in th above, except that now it is assumed that $E[\varepsilon\varepsilon^{T}] = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_{1}^{2}, \sigma^{2}_{2}, \dots, \sigma_{n}^{2})$, so each residual $\varepsilon_{i}$ has a different variance, but all residuals are still uncorrelated. In this case, OLS is no longer optimal, and the weighted least squares estimator is now BLUE.
In-sample you will of course never find that things match up perfectly with your model assumptions, i.e. under homoskedasticity even you won't find that all residuals $e^{2}(x_{i},\beta)$ are exactly the same, but you can do tests to see whether this is the case (see e.g. here). Similar tests for autocorrelation (i.e. fully unrestricted covariance matrix $\Sigma$) also exist, but then you should use generalized least squares.
Since in practice you never know the true $\sigma_{i}^{2}$ under heteroskedasticity, there is a procedure called feasible weighted/generalized least squares (see here), which aims to estimate the weights.
